# Accesing global variables inside lib folder in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables, rails-i18n, lib

So in my application_controller, i have a method called switch_locale that is being executed all the time (around_action), and the method is setting a variable called I18n.locale (is related with translations)

```
def switch_locale(&action)
    if current_user
      I18n.locale = current_user.try(:preferred_locale) || I18n.default_locale
      I18n.with_locale(I18n.locale, &action)
    else
      I18n.with_locale(I18n.locale, &action)
    end
    $locale = I18n.locale
  end
```

Inside my lib folder, i have a file in /lib/module/name_of_module/config/init.rb that is the only one in the whole project that does not have access to this variable. I tried setting a gloval variable in the switch_locale method inside application_controller like

```
@locale = I18n.locale
```

but then again i cannot access the variable @locale from this file. I'm really confused, what is happening? at first i thought this file was being executed just one time before the application.rb, then i put some loggers and i saw that this is not the problem, the loggers get executed from time to time.

so my question is, why it doesnt have access? why the variable setted in the application_controller is not accessible from the init.rb? why i cannot access also the global variable @locale?

I'm really confused so thanks to whoever can help me.

Things that i tried:

- putting the path to those files inside the application.rb with the config.eager_load_paths
- creating a file in config/initializers that reloads the lib folder, and creating a function inside application_controller that gets executed before_filter or even around_action as my other function

none of these worked, since the problem was not the autoloading of the files, but the access to that variable.

edit: just in case, but the lib/ folder is not inside app/. they are at the same level. I read some solutions like placing the lib/ folder inside app/ but i dont want to do this, since i also saw it was not that good of a solution.

edit2: as suggested, i tried using the $ instead of @ and is also not working, is like the init.rb doesnt know about this variable.

Comment: `@locale` wil be an instance variable of your controller, not a global variable, a global variable is defined using a `$`. But you could probably access `I18n.locale` right from your lib file ? see: https://www.thoughtco.com/global-variables-2908384

Comment: I mean i can access I18n.locale, but the thing is that is not being updated with the value from switch_locale. In the past i did in this init.rb file something like: I18n.locale = :es, so now the value of the variable in this file is always ES, it doesnt change even when i change the language to english and the whole project changes, except this one.

Comment: Are you setting the locale properly with `I18n.with_locale(locale, &block)` and not `I18n.locale = :some_locale` as explained [by the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests)?

Comment: updated my question with the method i have, and yes, im using that.